# Unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: typescript, dependencies, nestjs, eslint, nomachine-nx

I have a problem with dependencies in the project. Below is the error code I get when trying to update packages. I also paste the code of my dependencies in the "package.json" file.

```
ERROR CODE
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: grocery-shop@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.47.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ERR!   dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.47.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.1" from eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@21.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript
npm ERR!   dev eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@"^21.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/pk/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pk/.npm/_logs/2022-12-29T13_36_27_051Z-debug-0.log
```

```
package.json file

  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/nest": "^15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/node": "15.3.3",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.3.3",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.1",
    "@types/node": "18.7.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.47.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^21.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.1.0",
    "nx": "15.3.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prisma": "^4.8.0",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
```

I've tried to use "audit fix" command or "npm install"/"update" with "--force" and "--legacy-peer-deps" but the problem still occurs. Do you guys have an idea how to fix this? Which dependencies are the problem and what versions to change to?

Answer (score 0):

[From the looks of their changelog](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) I would guess that you need to use `eslint-config-standard-with-typescript` version 22 and on. Version 24 was just released two weeks ago and explicitly has `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` set to a high enough version for sure. [Going back to the oldest commit that has that version](https://github.com/standard/eslint-config-standard-with-typescript/commit/dc25743534d992f6607bb2d391c7ab9d2c143d61) it looks like you should use `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@^22` if you want the oldest compatible version or just `npm install --save-dev eslint-config-standard-with-typescript@latest` to get the newest version